# Why do LaTeX and pdflatex produce different margins?

Tags: pdftex, margins, dvips

I am working with TeXStudio on Windows. When I use latex + dvips + ps2pdf and pdflatex the margins in the resulting  PDF file are different.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a way to avoid this?

---

The code below produced different margins at the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't [reproduce](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4tHBGfLb) the problem. Compare [this](http://i.imgur.com/mJq947x.png) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/N85sONW.png). Could you provide a [minimal working example?](http://goo.gl/5XLQU)

Comment: Probably the page format is different (letter versus a4). And yes you can avoid it by passing the correct options.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are using MikTeX. You need to pass `-sPAPERSIZE#a4` to `ps2pdf` to get the same margin.

Comment: @OP, just to inform: configure TeXstudio and insert the option suggested above on the command line of ps2pdf.